# how can i add signature in text area field of php code

Tags: php, html, html5-canvas

i wanted to add signature text at the end of message box but for users it must show a blank text box but when the user click send then signature also go with that message  here is the code area where im trying to add my signature

```
<textarea name="text" cols="46" rows="10" onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.text,this.form.tabn,440);" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.text,this.form.tabn,440);"></textarea>
```

Comment: If you have control over the sending code, you can just attach it server-side in your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it on the php side, or you can use javascript to add it when the user submits the form.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$signature = "Your signature";
$name .= $signature;
...

?>
```

Comment: oops meant to put .=

Comment: +1 No permanent damage ;)